# Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed is safe to use?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-10, temporary-files

What does `"Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed"` setting actually do?

1. Clears files every time when IE closed?
2. Normally in IE when Temporary Internet Files are cleared? 
   Is it cleared only if user clears it manually or any scheduled basic or memory,size basis etc..
3. Is there any disadvantage of using "Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed" settings?
4. We are using lot of web embedded application(web browser control) so does this setting will cause any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but this doesn't mean they magically vanish as a whole. They're just deleted and it's still possible to use tools to restore those files.
2. There are multiple things considered here. There can be a time limit issued by the web server as part of the HTTP header for example. Also there's the fixed maximum size for Temporary Internet Files (found in Internet options). Plus it also happens if you specifically tell it to remove them.
3. None, other than always fetching the same files, even if they never change, which might slow down browsing the first time you visit a site during a session. Also this will increase your bandwidth usage.
4. It shouldn't, except the points described under point 3.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Internet Files are all files that are being downloaded when navigating a website. Included are images and files you downloaded when pressing the <kbd>run</kbd> button instead of the <kbd>save as...</kbd> button.

The setting `Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed` will clear all these files.

`+` The advantages are that your harddrive won't fill up diskspace due to files no longer being used are deleted.

`-` The disadvantages are that because all the files are being deleted, including images, loading websites next time will be slower and it uses up more bandwidth.

On average, the storage space on the Temporary Internet Files location is not huge, and cleaning only once in a while would suffice, unless you really need your diskspace.

As per your point 2: cleaning either happens by you, or the setting automatically at each close. There are programs that do scheduled maintainance that will clean this as well, including the windows disk cleanup utility, but if they are not running/scheduled to run, the temporary internet files storage location will not be cleared.